# Which flag to use for better quality with sws_scale?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
/* values for the flags, the stuff on the command line is different */
#define SWS_FAST_BILINEAR     1
#define SWS_BILINEAR          2
#define SWS_BICUBIC           4
#define SWS_X                 8
#define SWS_POINT          0x10
#define SWS_AREA           0x20
#define SWS_BICUBLIN       0x40
#define SWS_GAUSS          0x80
#define SWS_SINC          0x100
#define SWS_LANCZOS       0x200
#define SWS_SPLINE        0x400
```

Which one is better for image quality? What are differences? Are they all lossy?
I'm trying to convert RGB24 into YUV420P.

Answer (score 2):

The RGB24 to YUV420 conversation itself is lossy. The scaling algorithm is probably used in downscaling the color information. I'd say the quality is:
point << bilinear < bicubic < lanczos/sinc/spline
I don't really know the others.
Under rare circumstances sinc is the ideal scaler and lossless, but those conditions are usually not met.
Are you also scaling the video? Otherwise I'd go for bicubic.

Comment: I'm preparing frames for encoding, I have RGB24 frames and AFAIU I need them to be converted into YUV420p before passing into avcodec_encode_video2. As for scaling: size is not changed during scaling. Does it mean I can use 0 with the flag?

Comment: The conversion from RGB to YUV involves no scaling. The conversion from YUV444 to YUV420 reduces the resolution of the color planes and thus involves scaling. You should try different values and see if you can see a difference and which looks best to your eyes. Otherwise I'd just go for Bicubic or even Bilinear.

Comment: But if no scaling involved then the flag is not needed (can be zero). Right? I tried different flags, but I was not able to see any differences. Though, fast bilinear worked faster (profiled it). But if it worked faster with fast bilinear then the flag is involved... hmmm... :)

Comment: Scaling is involved, the color information is downscaled.

Comment: But you said "The conversion from RGB to YUV involves no scaling".

Comment: But YUV444 to YUV 420 does. RGB has 3 color planes at full resolution. YUV ist just a concept of separating Color from Luma information. YUV444 has one full resolution Luma plane and two full resolution color planes. YUV420 has full res luma and quarter res chroma.

Comment: Yeah but I don't use YUV444... I only convert RGB24 into YUV420p. Does it mean that YUV444 is used somewhere inside and implicitly during convertion from RGB24 to YUV420p?

Comment: I don't know exactly how ffmpeg does the conversion and it doesn't matter. The color information is downscaled, thus scaling is involved.

Comment: If ffmpeg has some algorithm to do RGB>YUV420 without going through YUV444, then maybe it doesn't matter what parameter you set. Just set it, if its not used, it is not used.